# Best database design for creating dynamic model properties in ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.mvc 4 and EF (not code first).

What's best database design for creating dynamic model properties;

example:
I have ProductModel and I know some properties and I can statically there. But I dont know some properties and I need create dynamically.
like this:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IList<DynamicPropertyValue> DynamicProperties {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you.

I have an application with dynamic fields. I created a table like this:

```
idField |name   |typeField  |minVal |maxVal |required  |enabled
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       |V-AB   |float      |0      |3500   |0         |1
2       |V-BC   |float      |0      |3500   |0         |1
3       |Desc   |String     |0      |256    |0         |1
```

And I use the field's table like this:

```
idMeasurementField  |idPumpMeasurement  |idField    |value
------------------------------------------------------------------------
121                 |14                 |3          |NIVEL ESTATICO
123                 |14                 |1          |66.78
124                 |14                 |2          |34.89
```